# common_rosdeps/rosdep.yaml does not working?

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had following problem

```
$ rosdep install openhrp3
Failed to find rosdep libxml2 for package openhrp3 on OS:ubuntu version:lucid rosdep install ERROR: failed to install libxml2
```

but it libxml2 is defined in the common_rosdeps/rosdep.yaml as

```
libxml2:
  ubuntu: libxml2-dev
  debian: libxml2-dev
  arch: libxml2
  opensuse: libxml2-devel
  fedora: libxml2-devel
  macports: libxml2
  gentoo: dev-libs/libxml2
  freebsd: libxml2
  fedora: libxml2
```

Is there somethig wrong in common_rosdeps stacks?

```
$ rosdep where_defined libxml2
libxml2 defined in set(['/opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_rosdeps/rosdep.yaml', ">>/opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_rosdeps/rosdep.yaml<<Unused due to package 'common_rosdeps' being in a stack.]]"])
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11806/common_rosdeps/rosdep.yaml-does-not-working?/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2011-11-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm am not familiar with the contents of openhrp3, but, in order to use common_rosdeps, you have to declare a dependency on it.  This can be declared as either a package or a stack dependency -- the package dependency is preferred.

e.g. "rospack depends openhrp3" must contain "common_rosdeps"

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2011-11-05**:
it works, thanks.